# Fastest/Easiest Way to Parse Text

Tags: java, text-parsing

I am trying to parse some text am looking for the fastest/easiest solution to do so.  I've tried using regex, but it is taking forever with Java...

Here's the structure of the text I am trying to parse:

```
*****************
ID: 1234567  // 7 digit uuid
mistakes: There may be some mistakes here, or there may not be any mistakes  //optional
mistake type: mistake background // "YES" or "NO"
report: <xml><item>blah, blah</item></xml> 

*****************
```

In reality the file might look as such:

```
*****************
ID: 1234567
mistakes: 
NO: happened on the playground
report: <xml><item>black eye when playing basketball</item><reason>elbow</reason></xml> 

*****************

*****************
ID: 1234568
mistakes: Teacher was not watching students at the time of incident
YES: teacher turned her back after seeing an altercation
report: <xml><item>fight</item><reason>None</reason></xml> 

*****************

*****************
ID: 1234569
mistakes:
NO
report: <xml><item>Child needed band-aid</item><reason>scrape</reason></xml> 

*****************

*****************
ID: 1234570
mistakes:
NO
report: <xml><item>Child needed tissue</item><reason>runny nose</reason></xml> 

*****************
...
...
```

I am trying to put the 'keys' (ID, mistakes, mistake type, report),  into a `Map` for further aggregation and processing.

I've tried using regex and had minimal success but the client keeps changing the report structure and throws the entire pattern off.  I am looking for something that might be a little easier to maintain.  In the past, I've had an easy time with xsl transforms on data like this, however this isn't pure xml and I don't know if Java will throw up or not given the current format.  I've asked the client if they're willing to change the format, but they're not interested in doing that.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to make this parsing easier to maintain?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I don't have the regex with me, but here's the gist of it

`ID:\s*(\\d{7}).*mistakes:\s*(\\d*).*mistake type:\s*(\\d*).*report:\s*(.*)`

Comment: Well, the regex must be pretty simple to describe this format, it probably is no big deal to update them whenever the format changes.

Comment: Every time I do an update, it causes a lot of headaches.  It seems to always break something and takes me a couple days of Googling, etc to figure out why

Comment: The format should not change so often in the first place... Could we see some code ?

Comment: Don't agree with a single regex for this. The file is following a strict structure which you should follow. At least for the last (report) you should parse separately as xml. Just stream through the lines expecting this structure and break on stars filling a list of your objects as you go.

Comment: @Vedran I am already parsing the report.  I am trying to focus on "picking out the keys" (ID, MISTAKE, MISTAKE TYPE, REPORT)

Comment: The keys are simply the part of the line at the left of the first `:`... Why is that complicated ? Please show some code

Comment: @Dici - I'm at home now.  I'll have to post once I'm back at work

Comment: @Dici -  That's the kicker, sometimes it doesn't have the ":" after.  Sometimes it does.  I know I need to push back on them to lock down a format, but they're too busy to have to deal with IT stuff.  They're trying to deal with parents and keeping kids safe

Comment: I think your question is not well specified, because your problem itself has not a clear specification and that's really the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on posts yet, that's why I will leave this as an answer. If you have a fixed number of fields you could read line by line and only write 6 lines after your line startsWith("^\.*"). Then you would proceed with storing them in the map using similar logic. If it startsWith("^mistakes:") you store whatever is left after stripping ":mistakes" as a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regular string operations. For example for a line containing

*ID: 1234567*

Something like

```
if (line.startsWith("ID:")
{
    String id = line.subString(3).trim();
}
```

Obviously check that the line is not blank/null beforehand. I am fairly sure it will be faster.

See also this blog post [Performance Comparison: Regex versus string operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/04/04/performance-comparison-regex-versus-string-operations.aspx)

Comment: I have over 200 of these "groups" to parse.  I dont want to parse them line by line.

Comment: sorry, without seeing the code, I thought a BufferedReader was being used. If your reading the whole file into memory, I still do not see the reason for regex, as the item identifiers are static. I usually use regex if the identifiers were something like ID1:, ID2, etc

Comment: If you do not recommend using a regex, what would you recommend?

Comment: @Dan: I have parsed files with thousands of lines using this type of operation. I don't think it ever took more than 2 seconds to parse. Are you sure you can't afford to use this method?

Comment: @Dan Regular string comparisons as in my answer.

Comment: @Voldemort.  I could do it this way, but I was looking for more elegance.

Comment: @Dan Regular expressions look cool and all, but as you already know they are easy to break. This is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll continue using regex's with a readline twist.

I'll change my regex to be `"\\*{17}.*\\*{17}"` and once I have them grouped by the '*', I can read them in line by line putting them into my map by their ID.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using java, why dont u try loading this file as properties file. And then you can read this using propFile.getProperty("key"). This way you might not need map or even if you need a map you can use propFile.propertyNames() use the enumertion and place it in a map.

Comment: Problem with this idea is that the same key value shows up multiple times in a file based on the example.